# error creating tile for microsoft-band

Tags: microsoft-band

I have been getting errors when trying to create a tile on my band.  I can't seem to get through it.  Here is the error:

```
namespace Band_Test_3
{
#if !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN
    public static class Program
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 4.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());
        }
    }
#endif

    partial class App : global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 4.0.0.0")]
        private bool _contentLoaded;

        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 4.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public void InitializeComponent()
        {
            if (_contentLoaded)
                return;

            _contentLoaded = true;
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BINDING_DEBUG_OUTPUT
            DebugSettings.BindingFailed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                global::System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.Message);
            };
#endif
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code. The error is happening on the andClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile) line:

```
private async void btnCreateTile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txbMessage.Text = "";

        // create a new Guid for the tile 
        // create a new tile with a new Guid 
        BandTile tile = new BandTile(tileGuid)
        {
             // enable badging (the count of unread messages)     
             IsBadgingEnabled = true,
             // set the name     
             Name = "Band Test",
             // set the icons     
             SmallIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/Certificate-WF Small.png"),
             TileIcon = await LoadIcon("ms-appx:///Assets/Certificate-WF.png")
            };

            await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: The top section was the error.  It would show up in Visual Studio when I hit the "await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile);" line.

Comment: What you've pasted is not an error message but the code which intercepts uncaught exceptions.  Without the actual exception type and message, we can only guess at what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

The most common errors I have seen for failing to add a tile are:

- Duplicate GUID for the tile as one already on the band. If you have installed the sample tiles with the sample apps then make sure you are using a GUID that is different from the sample apps. The best thing here is to generate your own GUID for your tile.
- Maximum number of tiles are installed on the band. To check this, the exception should contain the error message, but you can query the number of tiles installed or you can look at the number installed via the Microsoft Health App in the Manage Tiles view (the number of tiles free is listed towards the top).

If those do now help, then please past in the exception you are getting.

Comment: I generated a new GUID so I don't think that's the problem.  I tried with multiple GUIDs.  I removed one tile from the band as I thought it might be the same issue you identified but I still get the error.

Comment: Are you adding icons to the tile? If so, are they within the recommended sizes? I would make sure to capture all exceptions and see if the problem is being raised. In general the exceptions/errors thrown for add tile failures are good at pinpointing the problem.

Comment: Cannot access a disposed object.  Object name: 'BandClient'.

Comment: Sounds like your bandClient object has gone out of scope. How are you storing your pointer to it? Perhaps you need to move the storage location of your bandClient. I am assuming you are getting a reference to the BandClient in a connection method but are not storing that reference at a class level. Hence, when you try to access it again later it has gone out of scope and hence you get that error.

Comment: This is a test page so I kept it as a member variable at the page level.  One button connects to it.  The next button was running  'tiles = await bandClient.TileManager.GetTilesAsync();'